# Looking for a saliency map detection code for video processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video, video-processing, feature-extraction

I am looking for a code or an application which can extract the salient object  out of a video considering both context and motion,
or
an algorithm just for motion saliency map detection (motion contrast) so I can fuse it with a context_aware salient object detector that I have.

Actually I have tested context_aware saliency map detector already but it in some frame detects some part of background as salient object and I want to involve the motion and time in this detection so I can extract the exact salient object as it's possible.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the most popular approaches (although a bit dated) in the computer vision community is the graph based visual saliency (GBVS) model.

it uses a graph-based method to compute visual saliency. first, the same feature maps than in the fsm model are extracted. it leads to three multiscale feature maps: colors, intensity and orientations. then, a fully-connected graph is built over all grid locations of each feature map and a weight is assigned between each node. this weight depends on the spatial distance and the value of the feature map between nodes. finally, each graph is treated as markov chains to build an activation map where nodes which are highly dissimilar to surrounding nodes will be assigned high values. finally, all activation maps are ultimately merged into the final saliency map.

you can find matlab source code here: http://www.vision.caltech.edu/~harel/share/gbvs.php